# Mapping elements in an NSArray to their counts and getting the most frequent

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, collections, nsarray

I am working on presentation where I am comparing collections and algorithms of standard libraries of different languages. Help me to write effective and readable algorithm of this problem:

Metaprogramming language:

```
struct Tweet { id, time, text, url, user_id };
struct User { id, name, nick };
array<Tweet> tweets;
map<int, User> userDict;
```

Problem:

Find the user name who sent the greatest number of tweets with `url` field not equal to `nil`.
Also find the count of such tweets from this user.

I have started like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * countByUserId = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
foreach (Tweet * tweet in tweets)
    if (tweet.url != 0)
        countByUserId[tweet->user_id] = @(countByUserId[tweet->user_id] + 1);
```

Now I need to find key-value with max value.

This is my C++ code:

```
map<int,int> countByUserId;
for (auto it = tweets.begin(); it != tweets.end(); ++it)
    if (it->url != 0)
        countByUserId[it->user_id]++;

auto para = max_element(countByUserId.begin(),
                        countByUserId.end(),
                        [](pair<int,int> a, pair<int,int> b)
                        { return a.second < b.second; });

cout << "User = "  << userDict[para.first].name << endl
     << "Value = " << para.second << endl;
```

Comment: The pseudo code specifies a map of `int` to `User` but you have build a dictionary that maps `user_id` to `int`.  Personally I think the pseudo code got it backward, but you may or may not want to fix.

Comment: @jeffamaphone suppose `userDict` filled properly and organized like `map` for easily access user struct by its `id`.

Comment: What is the `int` in `map<int, User>`?  Is the int the user id, the count of tweets with urls, or something else?  It's worth noting that `NSMutableDictionary` won't let you use a raw int as a key since keys must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: @jeffamaphone ^this not answers to your question. Suppose `array` of tweets and `map` of users is most effective way to store entities to our mystic application :)

Comment: @jeffamaphone yes, `map<int, User>` allow access User struct by `id`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so `countByUserId` is not the `map<>` specified in the pseudo code.  You've just chosen not to use the available `map<>` because you don't need it.  I see.

Comment: @jeffamaphone for `Objective-C` language this `map` will be `NSDictionary` with `NSNumber` keys and `User` objects.

Comment: @k06a Be wary of the micro-benchmark trap in writing your conclusion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I need to find key-value with max value...

There may be ties, so you should look for all key-value pairs with the max value. You can compute the max in your loop, and then walk through the `NSDictionary` again, looking for it:

```
NSMutableDictionary * countByUserId = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSInteger max = -1;
foreach (Tweet * tweet in tweets) {
    if (tweet.url != 0) {
        int next = countByUserId[tweet->user_id].intValue + 1;
        countByUserId[tweet->user_id] = @(next);
        if (next > max) {
            max = next;
        }
    }
}
[countByUserId enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj intValue] == max) {
        NSLog(@"Found max for user: %@", key);
    }
}
```